# how to move a drawing in open processing

Tags: javascript, openprocess

I have created the image of a dinosaur in openprocessing.org using multiple lines of code. I want to move the dinosaur around the environment as a whole, but moveMouse fn only lets me use one shape at a time. Any advice?

Comment: could you add some code to your question please?

Comment: use the `translate(50, 50);` function in your mouse move

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the translate function in conjunction with the mouseX/Y vars

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(100);
}

function draw() {
    background(100); // Set background
    translate(mouseX, mouseY); // translate
    circle(0, 0, 20); // draw here
}
```